# Add custom event object to calendar, and sync with Outlook via Lightning Sync

Tags: custom-object, event, calendar, outlook, sync

I created a custom "Event" type of object, where our Sales Reps log client visits or calls. I offered the chance for our Sales Reps, to include another user on the event (like an engineer, who helped them during the meeting).

Can I add these events to the Sales Reps, AND the engineers Calendar?

Also, would I be able to synchronise these events with Exchange?

Comment: I do not know if I understood correctly, but I would approach it in a hierarchic way.1. Create relationship beetwen "Event__c" and Event. 2. Make Event for each contact(one for Sales Rep and one for engineer).

Comment: In my mind, my custom "Event" type of object is not necessarily related to the built-in Salesforce event objects. The only commonality it has, is that thay both have start/finish dates. But my custom event object has a lot of additional fields that were necessary for this use-case.

Comment: Well, if so, you have to duplicate a standard event for each contact or create a custom calendar based on the entry in this object.